# Backspace + keypress adds a character of a different language in neovim with neomutt on my mac

Tags: insert-mode, digraphs

I am a user of neomutt and I use neovim as my default editor.

However, when I delete a character via backspace, and then type the correct character, I sometimes get a strange character from a different language. To give an example, If have have the word "coe", and I want to change "e" to "d", then I naturally would press backspace and then "d". However, that inserts "coで".

I am running into this problem only when I run neovim though neomutt. When I run vim regularly, I don't encounter this issue.

Any idea what could cause this issue? I am a mac user.

Comment: Thats a digraph. I know it can be triggered in this way but there’s a way to turn that off

Comment: I'm not familiar with neomutt but if the problem only happens in neomutt then I think it is not a problem related to neovim which would make this question off topic. You should ask in their issue tracker: https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues. *EDIT* Ben might be right, using `set nodigraph` might solve the problem (See [`:h i_digraph`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html#i_digraph))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @D.BenKnoble and @statox have mentioned, this sounds like you have the `'digraph'` option set in Neovim but not in Vim.

Running `:set nodigraph` in a running instance of Neovim should fix the problem, and you can run `:verbose set digraph?` to find out what part of your configuration is setting this option so you can resolve the issue properly.

See [`:help i_digraph`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html#i_digraph) and [`:help 'digraph'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27digraph%27) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. And you were right. It was related to the digraph value set in vim.